# Guice database factory

Tags: java, mysql, dependency-injection, guice, factory

I have an Java project and I need to implement Guice.

I have a modular project, so I can easily switch between databases. To do that I have I DBConnection factory that looks like this:

```
    public abstract class DBConnectionFactory {
    // List of DAO types supported by the factory
    public static final int MYSQL = 1;
    public static final int ORACLE = 2;

    public abstract FilterDAO getFilterDAO();
    public abstract PhotoDAO getPhotoDAO();
    public abstract SetDAO getSetDAO();

    public static DBConnectionFactory getDBConnectionFactory(int whichFactory) {
        switch (whichFactory)   {
            case MYSQL:
                return new MySQLFactory();
            case ORACLE:
                return new OracleFactory();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The factory returns an connection which looks for MySQL like this:

```
  public class MySQLFactory extends DBConnectionFactory {
    public static final String DRIVER= "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    public static final String DBURL= "jdbcurl";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final String USERNAME = "username";

    // method to create MySQL connection
    public static Connection createConnection() {
        try {
            // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            return connect;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public FilterDAO getFilterDAO() { return new MySQLFilterDAO(); }
    public PhotoDAO getPhotoDAO() {
        return new MySQLPhotoDAO();
    }
    public SetDAO getSetDAO() {
        return new MySQLSetDAO();
    }
}
```

In my ServletController I have this code to establish the connection:

```
// Create a DAO
private DBConnectionFactory MySQLFactory = DBConnectionFactory.getDBConnectionFactory(DBConnectionFactory.MYSQL);

@Override
public void init(){
    photoDAO = MySQLFactory.getPhotoDAO();
}
```

I'm trying to get rid of the factory and use Guice, but I don't know where to start. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The basic premise of guice is that you won't need all these factories anymore. You can `bind(PhotoDAOInterface.class).to(PhotoDAOImpl.class)` and `@Inject` them into constructors of other classes. Each `PhotoDAOImpl` could have configuration values injected into the constructor so that you can easily test the classes seperately. Factories are not easily tested.  So to provide a basic example: `@Inject public ServletController(PhotoDAO photoDAO) { this.photoDAO = photoDAO; }` For testing you could `bind(PhotoDAOInterface.class).to(PhotoDAOTestingImpl.class)` and nothing changes!

Comment: Thanks! But how do I now define which database I use? (MySQL or Oracle?)

Comment: Assuming both `MySQLConnection` and `OracleConnection` use the same interface. Use guice to `@Inject` a different kind of connection into the constructor of `FlagDAO`. Check out my answer below for a more understandable description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment and provide a better example. This assumes play framework but the principle should be quite the same.

The first thing you need to do when using Guice is bind implementations to interfaces. For instance I need a `FlagDAO`.

```
public interface FlagDAO {
    public Flag getByName(String name) throws FlagNotFoundException;
}
```

Now I have a couple of implementations of it of which I won't show the code entirely:

```
// This one is used in production/development
public class FlagDAOEbean implements FlagDAO {
    // Some code
}

// This one is used for testing
public class FlagDAOInMemory implements FlagDAO { {
    // Some code
}
```

To use the `FlagDAO` in some other service. This `SomethingUsingFlagDAO` class must also be constructed through Guice so the proper values are injected

```
public class SomethingUsingFlagDAO {
    @Inject
    public SomethingUsingFlagDAO(FlagDAO flagDAO) {
    }
}
```

Now play framework uses modules to bind certain stuff on application startup. I have disabled this module in testing but the code is run in development and production environment.

```
public class DAOModule extends AbstractModule {
    public void configure() {
        bind(FlagDAO.class).to(FlagDAOEbean.class);
        bind(SomethingUsingFlagDAOInterface.class).to(SomethingUsingFlagDAO.class);
    }
}
```

I have this code on my testcases. Note that the only thing that is actually different is which `FlagDAO` implementation is bound to Guice:

```
public class FlagsTest extends WithApplication {

    private SomethingUsingFlagDAO something;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Injector injector = this.provideApplication().injector();
        this.something = injector.instanceOf(SomethingUsingFlagDAO.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected Application provideApplication() {
        Application application = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
                .in(new Environment(new File("./"), this.getClass().getClassLoader(), Mode.TEST))
                .bindings(bind(FlagDAO.class).to(FlagDAOInMemory.class))
                .bindings(bind(SomethingUsingFlagDAOInterface.class).to(SomethingUsingFlagDAO.class))
                .build();

        return application;
    }
}
```

So depending on whether we are in a development/production/testing environment a different DAO implementation is used without actually changing how anything works. No `if (application.isTesting())` checks where they should not be.

---

In your case you could imagine a `FlagDAOOracle` alongside the `FlagDOAEbean` and `FlagDAOInMemory` which is bound like so:

```
public class DAOModule extends AbstractModule {
    public void configure() {
        if(weNeedOracle) {
           bind(FlagDAO.class).to(FlagDAOOracle.class);
        } else {
           bind(FlagDAO.class).to(FlagDAOMysql.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very clear explanation. But I'm facing the problem that I have a servlet controller, which doesn't have a controller, but who needs the injection. Any workaround?

Comment: You mean you cannot use the constructor? I think you could try this: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Servlets

Comment: I still don't get how you could inject in a servlet. I've tried every option I could come up with. Any ideas of how an implementation of a servlet with controller would look like? Thanks for your time